# Using CakeResponse in CakePHP application

Tags: php, cakephp, http-headers, cakephp-2.0, httpresponse

I'm trying to use [CakeResponse](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cakeresponse) in my CakePHP 2.2 application.
When I use this, I can see my response in page's headers. This is ok:

```
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
```

But when I do this I can't see it in headers.

```
$this->response->header('Last-Modified:', gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
$this->response->header('Last-Modified', gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
```

This also doesn't help:

```
$this->response->modified(gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
```

Should I make any more thing to use response object?

Answer (score 0):

Try without the `:`, like this:

```
$this->response->header('Last-Modified', gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
```

Comment: What application are you using to see the headers? I checked it with FireBug and i can confirm that Last-Modified was added to the header response.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't understand. what do you mean with application? I use CakePHP 2.2

Comment: Sorry i ment tool. What tool are you using to read the header?

Comment: I use Google Chrome's network tool. I also check with HTTP Headers plugin of Chrome. I can see correct headers when I set it with `header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');` syntax. I also change controller action name every time, to not to see old header values.

Comment: I just tested it with Chrome's network tool and it works correctly. I am using CakePHP version 2.2.3.
When i add the line `$this->response->header('Last-Modified', gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');` i see `Last-Modified:Wed, 28 Nov 2012 09:54:04 GMT` in the Response Headers